# How to make a result of a function as an element of a derived type class?

Tags: pointers, types, fortran

I'm trying to create an abstract element and be able to work without saying explicitly who the element is; that is for example create a vector and perform some operation with its elements regardless who the vector is.

Here is an example code

```
module reso
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
implicit none

type datos  
real(dp) :: x1,x2
integer :: longitud
contains
end type datos

abstract interface
function WW(r)
import
type(datos), intent(in) :: r
real(dp),dimension(r%longitud) :: WW
end function
end interface 

type vector
contains
procedure(WW),nopass, pointer :: vec=>linspace
end type

contains
function linspace(r) result (v)
type(datos), intent(in) :: r
real(dp),dimension(r%longitud) :: v
integer :: i
real(dp) :: incremento 
incremento = (r%x2-r%x1)/(real(r%longitud-1))
forall (i=1:r%longitud) v(i) = incremento*(i-1)+r%x1
end function linspace

end module reso

module operation
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
use reso

implicit none

contains

function diff(r,c) result (dd)
type(vector),intent(in) :: r
type (datos),intent(in) :: c
real(dp), dimension(c%longitud-1) :: dd
integer:: i
do i = 1:c%longitud-1
dd(i) = r%vec(c)(i+1) - r%vec(c)(i)
end do
end function diff

end module operation


program main
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
use reso
use operation
type (datos) ::d
d%x1 = 5.0d0
d%x2 = 7.0d0
d%longitud = 3

type(vector) :: v

print*,  v%vec(d)
print*,  v%vec(d)(1)

print*, diff(v,d)

end program main
```

The main idea of these modules is to create the array and I would like to be able to execute operations with the result of the function `linspace`. That is why I'm creating the pointer inside `type vector`. But this isn't working as I expected because I'm having the following error when I compile it with `gfortran-8`:
   `procedure(WW),nopass, pointer :: vec=>linspace
                        1
Error: Expected binding attribute at (1)`

Is there a way to do this properly and/or more neat?

Comment: Do you want the `vec` to be a type-bound procedure or a procedure pointer component? If the former, remove the `pointer` attribute; if the latter, remove the `contains`.  Beyond that, I don't see clearly what you intend: could you provide some other examples of what you hope to manage?

Comment: @francescalus I'd like to make an object like `y%linspace` where it has the result of `linspace`. I think a more general to my purpose would be to make a function whose argument is an array but without creating inside the function, like for example `function (y) type(My_type),intent(in) :: y` and `y` has the array that I created previously but using for instance the function `linspace`.

Comment: Notwithstanding the compiler error, note that `dd(i) = r%vec(c)(i+1) - r%vec(c)(i)` will execute twice the *function* `vec` in each loop. There is no "abtract data" here.